Use a lambda which captures this to initialize a struct member cause a segment fault in clang?
I use a lambda which captures this to initialize the struct member std::function f. The program is expected to print 9, but got a Segmentation fault.
My compile command is clang++ prog.cc with clang17.0.1.
Anyway, gcc doesn't seem to have this problem.
There is my code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gQ20oATvoJAFjKPY
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    int num = 0;
    std::function<int()> f = [this] { return num; };
};

int main() {
    Foo b { 9 };
    std::cout << b.f() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Some warning may be generated by clang:
prog.cc:11:5: warning: stack frame size (1099511627768) exceeds limit (4294967295) in 'main' [-Wframe-larger-than]
   11 | int main() {
      |     ^
In file included from prog.cc:4:
In file included from /opt/wandbox/clang-17.0.1/include/c++/v1/functional:529:
/opt/wandbox/clang-17.0.1/include/c++/v1/__functional/function.h:310:70: warning: stack frame size (1099511627768) exceeds limit (4294967295) in 'std::__1::__function::__func<LonghistBackend::f::'lambda'(), std::__1::allocator<LonghistBackend::f::'lambda'()>, int ()>::__clone() const' [-Wframe-larger-than]
  310 |     _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI_VIRTUAL virtual __base<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)>* __clone() const;
      |                                                                      ^
2 warnings generated.

It seems something to do with implement of standard library.
Does anyone has ideas about this?

Looks like a wandbox problem, cannot reproduce it with godbolt with same compiler and flags: https://godbolt.org/z/asefj9vEE

It has nothing to do with any capturing or lambdas or structs. clang 17 also gives a segmentation fault for the minimal program int main() {}, so I would say that it's definitely wandbox's fault. (And clang 16 gives a bus error rather than a segmentation fault.)

However, do reproduce with our company build system. It really seems something to do with standard library not clang. I apologize for this.

This is a common wandbox problem. Start using godbolt where clang 17.0.1 doesn't segfault.

I found these static assert is true. But as I know, std::string and std::function are both 32 bytes?
static_assert(sizeof(std::string) == 24, "");
static_assert(sizeof(std::function<void()>) == 48, "");

Your company build system seems to be misconfigured. And the sizes of std::string and std::function are implementation-dependent (and sometimes also depend on whether it's a debug build or not). But those sizes don't have anything to do with anything here.

Notice that defaulted copy/move constructor are wrong, as they will refer to the "old" this, leading probably to dangling pointer.

This seems to be a wandbox specific bug/error.
There are already reported programs that reproduces the error. We don't even need a lambda to reproduce the error.
First reported program for c++ with clang 17.0.1
Second reported program for C with clang 16.0.4
Both of these errors were found using this query

There is also issue: clang(++) unhelpful frame-larger-than warning, very small stack frame exceeding very large limit that has been fixed with later versions.
